# How to update my Fragment List From my Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, adapter

I would like to change dynamically my `List` of `Fragment` which will be sent to an adapter in Parent `Activity`.

I have tried to send it by a `Bundle` but the `RecyclerView` is not refreshed.

I also have tried to implement a method in my `Fragment` to be called from my `Activity`.

What's the best way the do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for observer pattern
https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern
The idea is making your fragment like an observer for any updates

Comment: interesting, i will try to do it